# This email is too generic for verification Github

Tags: git, email, github

My Github contributions are not counted on the contributions graph.
I followed this link: https://help.github.com/articles/i-don-t-see-myself-in-the-repository-contributors-graph/
Found that I needed to add my link to my github settings, however, my email is something like this:
MikeSmith@Mikes-MacBook-Pro.local
And here comes the problem, Github complains: This email is too generic for verification. Thus, I cannot get my email verified and my commits to Github will never be counted.

I'm thinking about solutions to this issue.
How could I change my email to a less generic one? Or any other ideas to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a problem with using your actual email address, like from Google, instead?

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not Github technical support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I typed this command in my git repo directory:

```
git config user.email MY_ACTUAL_GMAIL@gmail.com
```

to change that very generic email to my actual gmail, then it works! 
Cheers!